# How to create a string filter script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I want to create a python (python 3) script that can filter a string to a specific 6 letters, 3 numbers and 2 special characters

Here is what I've done so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

#lower_letters
letters = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']

#upper_letters
upper_letters = []
for letter in letters:
    letter = letter.upper()
    upper_letters.append(letter)

#numbers
numbers = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']

#special_caracters
special_caracters = ['~','`','!','@','#','$','%','^','&','*','(',')','-','_','+','=','{','}','[',']','|','/',':',';','"',"'",'<','>','.',',','?']

alph_num = 6
num_num = 3
caract_num = 2

string = 'alphabets123456@@'
filtered_string = ?
```

I expect filtered_string to contain only 6 letters, 3 numbers and 2 special chars. Like

```
filtered_string = 'alphab123@@'
```

Comment: You can use regex.

Comment: How? if you dont mind can you show me how?

Comment: Do you want to trim down the strings to include only 6 letters, 3 numbers and 2 special chars? Is that correct?

Comment: What _specific_ 6 letters, 3 numbers and 2 special characters do you want to limit the string to? It doesn't appear like you made any attempt to do this yourself.

Comment: how do you expect `filtered_string` to be?

Comment: By regex Mushif means a regular expression - you can start with matching letters - the character class `[a-zA-Z]` will match a single letter. This is supported by the python `re` module.

Comment: See [Regular Expression HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) in the documentation.

Comment: Yes i want to somehow limit that string to contain only 6 letters, 3 numbers and 2 special chars

Comment: I expect filtered_string to contain only 6 letters, 3 numbers and 2 special chars. Like filtered_string='alphab123@@'

Comment: yes its used in cyber security

Comment: @tripleee Initially, I thought the same that's why I suggested using a regex. But then OP provided more information in the question and the expected output made it clear that it's not validation. It's like modifying a string and removing extra characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I misunderstood what you meant by filter string. I thought you wanted to validate if a string is matching a particular pattern, that's why I suggested using a Regex (Regular expression).

For this kind of filtering, you may want to do something like this (although it's not very efficient but I tried to keep it simple):

```
alpha_count = 0
num_count = 0
special_count = 0
filtered_string = ''

for ch in string:
    if ch.isalpha() and alpha_count < 6:
        filtered_string += ch
        alpha_count += 1
    elif ch.isdigit() and num_count < 3:
        filtered_string += ch
        num_count += 1
    elif ch in special_characters and special_count < 2:
        filtered_string += ch
        special_count += 1

print(filtered_string)  # prints: alphab123@@
```

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using a standard for loop over each character in the string, and adding it too the final string if you have not seen enough of that type of character yet.

Note you may want to append to a temporary list and use `str.join` at the end, rather then use `+=` since the prior is amortized `O(1)` while the later is `O(n)` for each append. For a similar reason you would want to store `special_characters` as a set rather than a list:

```
def filter_string(s):
    special_characters = {
        '~', '`', '!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', '-', '_',
        '+', '=', '{', '}', '[', ']', '|', '/', ':', ';', '"', "'", '<', '>',
        '.', ',', '?'
    }
    max_alpha, max_digit, max_special = 6, 3, 2
    num_alpha, num_digit, num_special = 0, 0, 0
    result = []
    for c in s:
        if c.isalpha() and num_alpha < max_alpha:
            num_alpha += 1
            result.append(c)
        elif c.isdigit() and num_digit < max_digit:
            num_digit += 1
            result.append(c)
        elif c in special_characters and num_special < max_special:
            num_special += 1
            result.append(c)
    return ''.join(result)


string = "alphabets123456@@"
filtered_string = filter_string(string)
print(filtered_string)
```

**Output:**

```
alphab123@@
```